# Usage of current-buffer in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using emacs and I have written a script which uses "current-buffer". However the emacs system doesn't recognise "current-buffer". When I try "M - x current-buffer" i get the response:

no match

: Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`current-buffer` is not an interactive function.  That is, can't be invoked interactively via `M-x` as you've tried to do.  You can execute non-interactive lisp-code directly by using `eval-expression` as follows:

```
M-: (current-buffer) RET
```

Notice that you have to enter a proper lisp expression.  If you want to capture the value in a variable, something like this

```
M-: (setq xyzzy (current-buffer)) RET
```

will store the current buffer into the variable `xyzzy`.

Comment: When i try "M-: (current-buffer) RET" I get the answer "Trailing garbage following expression"

Comment: Sorry, RET means to hit the return key.  This is one of the conventions in emacs's builtin documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Do I interpret you correct that you have created a function named `current-buffer` that you want to be available with `M-x current-buffer`?

To enable functions to be called by `M-x function-name` the function needs to be marked as interactive.

A sample from the [emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Interactive-multiply_002dby_002dseven.html#Interactive-multiply_002dby_002dseven):

```
(defun multiply-by-seven (number)       ; Interactive version.
       "Multiply NUMBER by seven."
       (interactive "p")
       (message "The result is %d" (* 7 number)))
```

The `(interactive "p")` part makes the function callable from the minibuffer (through `M-x`).

Comment: I haven't created a function called "current-buffer", but I do know what you mean about functions needing to be interactive, I just didn't know if it applied to "current-buffer". Is there any way to output the value of "current-buffer"?

Comment: If current-buffer isn't an interactive function, you cannot call it from the minibuffer. One simple solution is to create your own interactive wrapper function.

Comment: Where should I send the output of the function? In "message"?

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you would (also) like to know how to get the name of the current buffer interactively.  Use `M-: (buffer-name)`.